# What happened at the end of Prince of Persia (2008)?

Tags: prince-of-persia-2008

I do not understand what happened to the Prince and to Elika at the end of *Prince of Persia (2008)*.

Did they die? Are they still alive?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the first couple of questions, but we will not be able to tell you whether there will be a sequel and questions that speculate on the future of games are off topic.

Comment: Could you read through the sites [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) you've had a couple downvoted questions in a short period.

Comment: There's a DLC entitled "Epilogue" that answers this question.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock you just Forgot to mention that it was exclusive to XBOX360 and PS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a video of the end of Prince of Persia (2008):

[The following contains spoilers... which you probably expected anyway in this thread.]

> At the very end, it is pretty clear that both the Prince and Elika are not dead.  Elika has been raised back to life by the Prince, while at the same time unleashing a terrible evil. The fact that they are not dead is further shown by the existence of the Prince of Persia Epilogue, a sequel to the game, which contains both the Prince and Elika.

Here is the ending of the Epilogue: